# How to flatten one layer of list of list of lists in python?

Tags: python

I have a structure of the form:

```
lst= [[['A'], ['B'], ['C']], [['A'], ['B'], ['D'], ['E']], [['B'], ['C']]]
```

I want to collapse the innermost layers of the lists such that I get the following structure:

```
lst= [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'C']]
```

I have tried to flatten the list by doing:

```
[item for sublst in lst for item in sublst]
```

But this collapses all layers instead to a one dimensional list.

What is the most pythonic way to address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flatten the *elements* of `lst`, not `lst` itself.

So use the double loop list comprehension *inside another list comprehension*, where the outer comprehension iterates over your top-level list:

```
[[item for inner in sublst for item in inner] for sublst in lst]
```

Since your inner-most lists each only contain a single element, you could also use indexing to get those values:

```
[[inner[0] for inner in sublst] for sublst in lst]
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [[['A'], ['B'], ['C']], [['A'], ['B'], ['D'], ['E']], [['B'], ['C']]]
>>> [[item for inner in sublst for item in inner] for sublst in lst]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'C']]
>>> [[inner[0] for inner in sublst] for sublst in lst]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'C']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over sublists and index them to get desired output (but this assumes your inner list holds only one element):

```
lst= [[['A'], ['B'], ['C']], [['A'], ['B'], ['D'], ['E']], [['B'], ['C']]]

result = [[y[0] for y in x] for x in lst]
# [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'C']]
```

Optionally, you can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from `itertools` (Now this handles any number of elements in inner lists):

```
from itertools import chain

lst= [[['A'], ['B'], ['C']], [['A'], ['B'], ['D'], ['E']], [['B'], ['C']]]

result = [list(chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in lst]
```